# I would like to create a macro to fill in a percent grid automatically in the most efficient manner

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

I would like to create a macro that fills in the percent grid if I call `\mypercent{43}`, it will fill in 43 squares.  I'm doing it manually but would like help in automating the process.  Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{examdesign}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\SectionFont{\large\sffamily}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}  %%shortlabels here for matchign
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} %%%%%%%%%%%for marking angles
\usetkzobj{all}  %%%%%%%%%%%because of Overleaf
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,matrix}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,hypcap=false]{caption}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering
\ShortKey
%%\NoKey
\DefineAnswerWrapper{}{}
\NumberOfVersions{1}
%%%%%Title of the Assignment
\class{needed for examdesign}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{shortanswer}[title={Review of Percent},rearrange=no,resetcounter=yes]
\begin{question}
Shade in the percent grids to show the indicated percent.
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}
%\newcommand\mypercent{43}%This is the call. 
\item $43\%$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
%%%%%want the following to be in a macro
\foreach\x in {1,...,4}{
 \foreach \y in {0,-1,...,-10}
 \draw[draw=black,fill=black!20!white] (0,0) grid(\x,\y) rectangle (0,0);}
  \foreach \x in {4}{
 \foreach \y in {-3}
 \draw[draw=black,fill=black!20!white,line width=\pgflinewidth/2] (\x,0) grid(\x+1,\y) rectangle (\x,0);}
 %%%so the grid will draw over the top
 \draw [] (0,0) grid(10,-10);
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
\begin{answer}
answer here
    \end{answer}

\end{question}
\end{shortanswer}

\end{document}
```

Here is the picture.  [image: Percent example]
I wonder if the process could use an if conditional then a for loop.  Something like:
If the number is less then 10, fill in the number of squares in one column, 
if it is more than 10, fill in one column, shift to the next column, count down the number by 10 then repeat the loop.  Exit after the loop after the less than 10 condition.  In my code, I've had to draw the final grid on top to make sure the lines go over top.

I made the grid go down to make it more visually intuitive to count down.  Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible to do that. Let's first define a pic.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3,pics/percent grid/.style={code={
    \tikzset{percent grid/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/percent grid/##1}}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nx}{\pv{p}/10}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ny}{Mod(\pv{p},10)}
    \ifnum\nx=0
     \ifnum\ny=0
     \else
      \path[percent grid/pfill] (-5,5) rectangle (-4,5-\ny);
     \fi
    \else
     \ifnum\ny=0
      \path[percent grid/pfill] (-5,5) rectangle (-5+\nx,-5);
     \else
      \path[percent grid/pfill] (-5,5) |- (-5+\nx,-5) |- (-5+\nx+1,5-\ny) |-cycle;
     \fi
    \fi
    \draw[line cap=rect] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
 }},percent grid/.cd,p/.initial=0,pfill/.style={fill=black!20!white}]

 \path[transform shape] (0,0) pic{percent grid={p=43}}
  (12,0) pic{percent grid={p=3}}
  (0,-12) pic{percent grid={p=50}}
  (12,-12) pic{percent grid={p=100}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is macro version thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/percent grid/.style={code={
    \tikzset{percent grid/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/percent grid/##1}}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nx}{\pv{p}/10}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ny}{Mod(\pv{p},10)}
    \ifnum\nx=0
     \ifnum\ny=0
     \else
      \path[percent grid/pfill] (-5,5) rectangle (-4,5-\ny);
     \fi
    \else
     \ifnum\ny=0
      \path[percent grid/pfill] (-5,5) rectangle (-5+\nx,-5);
     \else
      \path[percent grid/pfill] (-5,5) |- (-5+\nx,-5) |- (-5+\nx+1,5-\ny) |-cycle;
     \fi
    \fi
    \draw[line cap=rect] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
 }},percent grid/.cd,p/.initial=0,pfill/.style={fill=black!20!white}}
\newcommand{\mypercent}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\pic[scale=0.3]{percent grid={p=#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}} 
\begin{document}
\mypercent{43}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: cat  Is it just a matter of personal preference or is there an advantage  or disadvantage of `\tikzset` vs the macro version?  I like the macro version because it looks cleaner.  Thank you for your help.  It will take me some time to study this.  For example I see the ny, but I'm not sure what `\pv` means... but as I learn, it may just be a new question to understand the inner workings.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @E.Yu If you are absolutely sure that you will always keep this scope of this precisely the same, the macro version is shorter. pgf keys allow you to add parameters later, so the command will be downwards compatible, you just add a new key. `\pv` is just a short cut here to access the value of the pgf key. E.g. `\pv{p}` evaluates to `\pgfpkeysvalueof{p}`, which is the key for the percentage.

Comment: oh yes, I see it now.  You defined it for a shortcut with `\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/percent grid/##1}}%`

Answer (score 6):

Who needs `TikZ`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,xcolor,graphicx}
\newcounter{z}
\newcommand\shazam[1]{%
\setcounter{z}{-#1}%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
\scalebox{-1}[1]{%
\fboxsep=0pt\relax%
\fbox{\parbox{100pt}{\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont%
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\relax%
\foreach\z in{1,...,10}{%
\foreach\zz in{1,...,10}{%
\ifnum\thez<0\relax\fbox{\color{gray}\rule{10pt}{10pt}}\else
  \fbox{\color{white}\rule{10pt}{10pt}}\fi
\stepcounter{z}%
}%
\ifnum\z<10\\\fi
}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\shazam{43}
\shazam{17}\medskip

\shazam{89}
\shazam{67}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ZOOM:

[image]

Comment: This is a cool answer too but to me, the lines look cleaner in Tikz but it may just be the image.  Thank you though.

Comment: @E.Yu I'm thinking it is just the image.  When you zoom on it, the lines are uniformly thick.